# QGIS clone QgsLayoutItemLegend or copy existing legend object

Tags: pyqgis

I have some legend object with my custom setting and styles:

```
exist_legend=QgsLayoutItemLegend()
```

How I can copy or clone or copy all setting and styles to new object legend, like this:

```
new_legend=exist_legend.clone()
```